# Database clarification issues

Tags: sql, database, parent-child, relationship

I’m nearing the end of a database project and I am having trouble clarifying some of the requirements.

First of all, why might someone require there to be more rows in the child table than in the parent table? I can’t seem to find a reason beyond individual preference.

Also, can someone make sense of this instruction?
*For items (table) add 2 more rows which you do not use other than their original entry.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is this an assignment? I'd personally ask your instructor if that's the case. This seems like a very open-ended question, and frankly isn't a good fit for SO. It's either Too Broad, or Opinionated.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example implemented in a system used in the industry since quite some time. It is about data and its representation in different languages.

Imagine a table that contains data in the system's base language (e.g. English). There are column data (e.g. description, short description and long description) that need to be translated into different languages (e.g. German, French and Spanish). The way it is designed is as follows:

- the parent table contains the data in the base language
- the child table contains the same keys plus an additional key named `language_cd` (which would have the language code, e.g. FRA or DEU or ESP) and each row/language code would contain the translated values

If I log on to the system in base language (e.g. ENG) then the base table would be used.

If I log on to the system in another language (e.g. FRA) then the base table would be joined with the child table so that the translated fields would be retrieved.

In regard to your last question/statement it is not clear or complete. More context would need to be given imo.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that makes a lot of sense. I apologize for the lack of clarity in the second part, I am unsure how to add detail. I just don’t understand the concept of including rows that will not be used.